# How do I avoid having to clear the cache when changing a module configuration parameter?

Tags: 8

I have a simple configuration parameter for a custom module. I use this parameter to decide how to render a field using a custom render element:

```
class Jmol extends RenderElement {

/**
 * Define the available options for our new render element.
 */
public function getInfo() {
$class = get_class($this);

// Produce the default settings for our render element.
return [
  '#pre_render' => [
    [$class, 'preRenderJmol'],
  ],
  '#version' => NULL,
  '#theme' => NULL,
  '#id' => 'mydiv',
  '#info' => [],
  '#attached' => [
    'library' => [],
  ],
];
}

public static function preRenderJmol($element) {

// Examine the config file to see which library version to use.
$config = \Drupal::config('jmol.settings');
$version = $config->get('version');
// Look at the element to see which version the user would like to use.
// They may have changed it from the default.
if ($element['#version'] != NULL) {
  $version = $element['#version'];
}

// The twig template to use.
$theme = "";

// Add the correct library to any the user has already provided.
$library = $element['#attached']['library'];
if ($version == 'full') {
  $theme = 'jmol_full_template';
  $library[] = 'jmol/jmol_full';
}
elseif ($version == 'lite') {
  $theme = 'jmol_lite_template';
  $library[] = 'jmol/jmol_lite';
}

// Only add the theme if the user has not specified one.
if ($element['#theme'] == NULL) {
  $element['#theme'] = $theme;
}

// Add the info array to drupalSetting so the JS can access it.
$id = $element['#id'];
$drupalsettings['jmol'][$id] = [
  'info' => $element['#info'],
];

$element['#attached'] = [
  'drupalSettings' => $drupalsettings,
  'library' => $library,
];

return $element;
}
```

If I visit the module settings page and change the value of the "version" parameter, my module continues to behave the same until I clear the cache.

The submit portion of my configuration form is:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('jmol.settings');
  $config->set('version', $form_state->getValue('jmol_version'))
  ->save();

  parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
}
```

Is there something else my submitForm function needs to do, or is there a different way I need to be reading the config parameter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the cache tag to invalidate your output if the configuration changes. That's as easy as adding this to your render array:

```
$element['#cache']['tags'] = $config->getCacheTags();
```