# drupalSettings cached in page

Tags: 8, caching

I have a module that adds functionality to the front-end. The feature can be turned on or off via the configuration page of the module.

I pass the settings to the frontend in the HTML preprocess function using `#attached`. Simplified, the code looks like this:

```
function my_module_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $config = \Drupal::config('my_module.settings');
  $settings = ['enabled' => $config->get('enabled')];
  $variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['my_module'] = $settings;
}
```

This approach is suggested here:

https://docs.acquia.com/tutorials/fast-track-drupal-8-coding/add-custom-variable-drupalsettings/

It works fine when logged in, but for anonymous users changing the setting from the module's configuration page does nothing until I clear caches (as, I assume, the drupalSettings variable is defined within the HTML that makes up the page)

So, my question:

- Is there a way to ensure the settings are fresh with each page load (without disabling the entire page cache, of course), or
- Should I refresh the cache whenever the module's configuration form is submitted? If so, what's the most efficient way to do that? (I've noticed a full cache clear is far slower on D8 than it was in D7)

Comment: This is probably a bit unclear as to get a good answer. I think someone might need to know more about your render array that you're attaching to. The concept you're looking for in Drupal 8 is regarding cache contexts and tags: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api. Depending on what you're doing there may be an appropriate cache tag/context or be able to disable only the cache for that part of the render array with max-age.

Comment: I've updated the code to show the full context.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I found the answer. It was as simple as adding this to `$variables`:

```
$variables['#cache']['tags'] = $config->getCacheTags();
```

My question is basically a duplicate of this:

[How do I avoid having to clear the cache when changing a module configuration parameter?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205867/how-do-i-avoid-having-to-clear-the-cache-when-changing-a-module-configuration-pa)